# specifying the store property to the _timestamp field using NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to specify the store property on the _timestamp field when programmatically creating a new mapping with NEST ?

this is a working syntax:

```
ES = new ElasticClient(settings);
var creatResult = ES.CreateIndex(pointedIndex, i =>
              i.NumberOfReplicas(Replicas)
              .NumberOfShards(Shards)
              .AddMapping<dynamic>(map =>
                map.TtlField(ttl => ttl.Enable(true).Default(string.Format("{0}d", TTLDays)))
                .TimestampField(ts => ts.Enabled(true))
                .Type("_default_")
                .RoutingField(rt => rt.Path("PartitionHashString").Required(false))
                 ));
```

what I'm missing is the ability to have a field in the TimestampFieldMappingDescriptor that references the store property on the timestamp field, so I would be able to do

```
ts.Enabled(true).Store(true);
```

does this worth mentioning on the NEST's issue page on github ?

Answer (score 0):

this was also posted by me to the NEST's github page, and will be addressed on the next release (1.7.1)

[github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1533)